# SSRS - expression format value required in bold

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to setup the value of a field as

Required Output

Date : **11/11/2011**

Present Expression I used as "Date : " & Parameters!ParamDateCreatedFrom.Value

Present Output value form the expression as

Date : 11/11/2011

here I am missing the date value in BOLD,

Any format in SSRS could help to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the "Date: " from the expression. You can do this by typing "Date: " directly into the text box, and then right click and select "Create Placeholder" from the menu. The formula for the placeholder can be `=Parameters!ParamDateCreatedFrom.Value`

Now you can apply formats to the placeholder without applying them to the label.

Comment: We could do this without the separation using html format options. I have implemented